# Select columns from a data file and place it in another file, with python

Tags: python

I'm new on python and I have a problem to solve.
I have a data file in columns and separated from blank spaces. I would just select some columns and write them to another text file (.txt or .dat doesn't matter), and I would like to do so so I can use this code for other files with different columns.
This is a sketch of my file:

```
        1     2332     2332 1.851E+14 1.851E+14 1377.93     0 0.000E+00  281.0788  680.7861  121.3181   588.19  -110.23  -116.67  774.44 -7.3979E+19       354169084    0.0162
        2     1528     1528 1.213E+14 1.213E+14 1197.00     0 0.000E+00  189.8768  285.5306   70.2188  -251.45   240.42  -793.13  623.65 -3.7264E+19       168917161    0.0124
        3     3247     3247 2.578E+14 2.578E+14 1538.90     0 0.000E+00  669.2193  332.7487  340.3935   -76.77   145.31   -70.35  778.94 -1.3707E+20       710525468    0.0252
```

I tried this:

```
import csv
csv_in = csv.reader(open('complete_lowtry.dat', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
csv_out = csv.writer(open('spam.dat', 'w'), delimiter=',')

for line in csv_in:
csv_out.writerow(line[8], line[9], line[10])
```

and another code:

```
import csv

csv_out = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

f = open('myfile.txt')
for line in f:
   vals = line.split('\t')
   csv_out.writerow(vals[8], vals[9], vals[10])
f.close()
```

that i found on the site. I want to take the columns 8,9 and 10, but in both cases I find the error:

```
csv_out.writerow(line[8], line[9], line[10])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone help me, please?
I'm a mac user and I use python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first program attempts to select **rows** 8,9, and 10 here:

```
for line in csv_in:
csv_out.writerow(line[8], line[9], line[10])
```

You're second program should not split on tabs. Use,

```
vals = line.split()
```

Although, I would really recommend using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org). Although you could totally do what you want without it.

You would do that as follows.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt('/path/to/data/file.txt')

selected_column_indecies = [8,9,10]
selected_columns = matrix[:,selected_column_indecies]

np.savetxt('/path/to/newdata/file.txt', selected_columns)
```

This works by loading the data file as a numpy array, using a list comprehension and "fancy" list indexing to get the selected columns, and then save them to a new file.

Install numpy with `pip install numpy`. If you don't have pip, install python with homebrew with `brew install python`. If you don't have homebrew,  [install it.](https://brew.sh)  You probably need all these things.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have already installed numpy.
I tried the code, create a file with three columns, but the numbers are wrong. For example, the first number in column 8 is 281.0788, while in the output file is 2.810788000000000011e + 02.
It happens for all the numbers ....

Comment: @AlessandroPeca  those numbers are not wrong. The first is a regular float. The second is in scientific notation and is correct up to float error! Not the e+02 at the end. You can save it in particular formats the the fmt param in the savetxt method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see it well. But how can this solve? I would rather have exactly the input file number with the same scientific notation...

Comment: @AlessandroPeca for sure!! NP does this by default for some reason. Pass the param fmt='%1.4f' into the savetxt method call.

Comment: wow, now it is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! But what's the meaning of fmt='%1.4f'?

Comment: @AlessandroPeca Ah! It is a standard formatting string. It means have all numbers before the decimal, and leave 4 after before truncating the float. More here. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code (both methods) is splitting on `\t`, but your problem description says the columns are separated by spaces. If there are no tabs in your data, both methods will consider each line to have a single column (numbered `0`) which is why `8` is out of range.

You can fix the second method by changing the call to `split()` so that it splits on one or more spaces:

```
import csv

csv_out = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

f = open('myfile.txt')
for line in f:
   vals = line.split()  # not \t
   csv_out.writerow([vals[8], vals[9], vals[10]])
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @BoarGules, but now the problem is:
TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: `writerow()` expects a list: `csv_out.writerow([vals[8], vals[9], vals[10]])` or `csv.writerow(vals[8:11])`. Sorry, I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: The first code produces a completely blank file, while the second one works. Thank you very much!